# transform dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries into dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of dict of dict, which I would like to convert in a dict of dict by combining the keys of the two outermost levels. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Here is the initial dict:

```
alldic={}
for a in range(3):
    machinedic={}
    for x in range(5):
        machinetimedic={}
        for i in range(4):
            machinetimedic["variable0"]=0
            machinetimedic["variable1"]=1
        machinedic["time "+str(x)]=machinetimedic
    alldic["machine "+str(a)]=machinedic
```

What I would like to have is a dict of dict that goes like that:

```
{'machine 0-time 0': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 0-time 1': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 0-time 2': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 0-time 3': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 0-time 4': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 1-time 0': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 1-time 1': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 1-time 2': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 1-time 3': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 1-time 4': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 2-time 0': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 2-time 1': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 2-time 2': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 2-time 3': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
  'machine 2-time 4': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1}}
```

Comment: Okay... but what do you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteration works beautifully:

```
>>> all_new_dic = {}
>>> for key in alldic:
for k in alldic[key]:
    new_key = key + '-' + k
    all_new_dic[new_key] = alldic[key][k]

>>> all_new_dic
{'machine 1-time 4': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 1-time 0': {'variable1': 1,      'variable0': 0}, 'machine 1-time 1': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 1-time 2': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 1-time 3': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 2-time 4': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 2-time 1': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 2-time 0': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 2-time 3': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 2-time 2': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 0-time 3': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 0-time 2': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 0-time 1': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 0-time 0': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}, 'machine 0-time 4': {'variable1': 1, 'variable0': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting, just flatten it like this

```
alldic={}
for a in range(3):
    machinedic={}
    for x in range(5):
        machinetimedic={}
        for i in range(4):
            machinetimedic["variable0"]=0
            machinetimedic["variable1"]=1
            alldic["machine {}-time {}".format(a, x)] = machinetimedic
```

Alternatively, you can get the same result, with dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> {"machine {}-time {}".format(a, x) : {"variable0": 0, "variable1" : 1}
        for a in range(3) for x in range(5)}
{'machine 0-time 0': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 0-time 1': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 0-time 2': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 0-time 3': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 0-time 4': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 1-time 0': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 1-time 1': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 1-time 2': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 1-time 3': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 1-time 4': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 2-time 0': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 2-time 1': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 2-time 2': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 2-time 3': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1},
 'machine 2-time 4': {'variable0': 0, 'variable1': 1}}
```